# C# - How do I install files to user that's using the application?

Tags: c#, authentication, installation, minecraft

I'm working on a custom Minecraft launcher for a buddy's server, & I need it to install files & also verify whether directories exist.

Currently its verifying directories on the C:\ drive's root, but I need it to direct towards whatever user is logged in, kind of like a wildcard.

```
 if (Directory.Exists(@"\users\currentuser\.minecraftlauncher") == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"\.minecraftlauncher");
        }
```

That's what I'm using, & the folder is being created on the C:\ drive. I hope I'm being clear, I've only been programming a few months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Environment.SpecialFolders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var userFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
var minecraftUserFolder = Path.Combine(userFolder, "minecraftlauncher");
if (!Directory.Exists(minecraftUserFolder))
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(minecraftUserFolder);
}
```